# java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible FCM

Tags: java, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, gson

I am getting this error on button clicked when sending firebase push notification

```
private fun sendNotification(notification: PushNotification) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(notification)
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: ${Gson().toJson(response)}")
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, response.errorBody().toString())
        }

    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please include the full exception stack trace in your question. Also note that `response` is a third party class, and by calling `Gson().toJson(response)` Gson might access internal fields of that class (which might be causing this issue). Would `Gson().toJson(response.body())` work for you?

Comment: @Marcono1234 is stack trace same w/ logcat? Sorry, im just a newbie. I’ll try this out thanks!

Comment: @norengx, you have to call [`Log.e(String, String, Throwable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#e(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) for that. In your case that is: `Log.e(TAG, "Failed sending notification", e);`. Then I think you should be able to obtain the stack trace from log cat.

Comment: @Marcono1234 this worked for me, I am able to receive my notifications now. I appreciate your help sir